# looking for prototyping and simulation software

Tags: software

I'm looking for open source software for modelling electronic circuits.

I have tried Arduino, Electric, Oregano, Fritzing, and QUCS so far. None of these seem to do what I want. I am looking for something like the Crocodile Clips software I was using some fifteen years ago.

I want to be able to **simulate interactively in real time**, with LEDs flashing on and off while I can push buttons and slide potentiometers around.

The aforementioned software seems to either not do simulation of this kind, or I haven't been able to find all the components I need (only basic stuff like NPNs, inductors, 555s).

Oh, an it ideally should run on Linux. I'm trying to run Crocodile Clips under Wine -- it's basically *exactly* what I want -- but it's highly unstable.

Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free circuit simulator for educational purposes](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24610/free-circuit-simulator-for-educational-purposes)

Answer (score 2):

very good educative circuit simulator: 
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Written in Java so you can run it on Linux