# Free online circuit simulator

Tags: simulation, website, freeware

Is there some free online circuit simulator where I can see see the electrons fluxing,imitating real-life circuitry?

Comment: I use Falstad: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ Very simplistic, but shows current flow.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a quick search on EE.SE I found: [Free circuit simulator for educational purposes](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24610/free-circuit-simulator-for-educational-purpose)

[Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/) seems to support animated electrons, and it is free.

However, if you are willing to shell out 10 bucks, I highly recommend [EveryCircuit](http://www.everycircuit.com). It supports

- Adjusting component values mid-simulation and seeing the effects in real-time.
- A large variety of components.
- Intuitive, and smooth animation: i.e. the electrons move faster for large currents/small currents, LEDs have varying brightness.

Here's a screenshot of EveryCircuit:

[image]

There is a free app version and an online version also.

Comment: http://everycircuit.com/app says "Chrome browser is required to run this App" :( I will not install Chrome just for this app.

Comment: CircuitJS has come a long way in the meantime; it does now have those features you bring up for EveryCircuit.. Maybe you can reevaluate and update this post : )